# How to login with an administrator account using OpenSSH on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, uac, openssh

I have just installed Cygwin and Openssh on my win7 box. After setting up the openssh, I can log in with my account (of course admin). But, I found my account under Ssh shell is filtered as a standard user.
I know this is because UAC, but I wanna my account under ssh shell is real admin.

update: here is a way to do this, quoted from [kb951016](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016):

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
3. If the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry entry does not exist, follow these steps:

   - On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
   - Type LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy, and then press ENTER.
4. Right-click LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy, and then click Modify.
   In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
   Exit Registry Editor.

Note: This change has a impact on system security, use it at your own risk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disable UAC as long as you want to ssh in it:

Control Panel -> search User Account Control.

Comment: Why are you posting in base64?

Comment: O wait? am i? A friend of mine is coding a browser, but it seems it doesnt work that well.. will edit the answer.

Comment: fixed with online decoder